# Multiple lines to single comma separated line in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I had converted single line to multiple lines and applied some transformations. Now I need to convert each individual line to single line

I tries using tupple but haven't wrked,

```
D = foreach grouped generate  group, COUNT(R);
requestFile = foreach D generate (bag{tuple(chararray)}) D.group as abc:{(group:chararray)};
G = GROUP requestFile ALL;
F = FOREACH G generate requestFile;
```

D has individual word and count of times it repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FLATTEN of BagToTuple to convert multiple rows to a single row like in the above code,

```
D = FOREACH grouped generate  group, COUNT(R);
G = GROUP D ALL;
F = FOREACH G generate FLATTEN(BagToTuple(D)) ;
```